# Is it possible to create a mail merge in Logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In the process of moving over to Azure ecosystem fully, I'm trying to recreate a mail merge via Logic apps.

The basic idea is we get the data output via stored proc with the test data similar to:

```
create table dbo.People (
Name nvarchar(255),
Local char(1) null,
Earned float null,
Email nvarchar(255) null
);

insert into dbo.People values ('Bob','N',20,'Bob@Fakemail.com');
insert into dbo.People values ('Bob','Y',28,'Bob@Fakemail.com');
insert into dbo.People values ('Jess','N',25,'Jess@Fakemail.com');
insert into dbo.People values ('Jess','Y',39,'Jess@Fakemail.com');
```

Is this doable in logic app? Trying to avoid paying for any addons.

Tried few tests and it seems to work fine with one line per name/person. Once it brings more than one line it duplicates the emails. Is there a way to combine them all?

[image: My Test LA] -- for for one line outputs (from SQL) of course it will duplicate if there is more than one. Though, not sure how to combine or process in bulk.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Appreciate tips and tricks!

Comment: Show your flow, might just be your implementation. It’s always good to provide as much info as possible.

Comment: Why don't you do a select distinct on your table from SQL?  i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT Name, Email FROM dbo.People`

Comment: Can do that sure, but I would like 2 lines to be sent to bob and 2 to Jess.

Comment: You need a distinct set of emails and then the set of lines for each person. It’s just logic, you can do that with two sql statements or in the logic app itself.

Comment: Ah so one will drive the loop and the other the data? I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could be able to achieve this by using 2 until loops where I have defined the condition to check for distinct emails and send the required details using outlook connector.

Alternatively, you can even use foreach loop instead of until if you use a similar logic. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

Initially, I have used 2 Queries. One to get the total table and other to get only the distinct emails.

[image]

In first Until loop, I have Set the Email to read the distinct emails

[image]

In the second until loop, I have used condition and if it is true, the required details will be appended to the array using the below expression.

```
{
     "Name":"@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Name']}",
     "Local":"@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Local']}",
     "Earned":"@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Earned']}",
     "Email":"@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Email']}"
}
```

[image]

Finally, I'm sending the updated variable through mail

[image]

Below is the complete Code view of my Logic App

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "SELECT * FROM dbo.People"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_-_Distinct_Emails": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM dbo.People"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_-_Details": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Details",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_-_Email": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_-_Email": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Email",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_-_Loop2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_-_Loop1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Loop1",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_-_Distinct_Emails": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_-_Loop2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Loop2",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_-_Loop1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Until_-_Loop1": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@variables('Details')",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Increment_variable_-_Loop1": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable_-_Loop1": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Loop1",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Until_-_Loop2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    },
                    "Set_variable_Details_to_null": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Details",
                            "value": "@null"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_variable_Loop2_to_0": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Set_variable_Distinct_Email": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Email",
                            "value": "@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_-_Distinct_Emails')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop1')]['Email']}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Set_variable_Loop2_to_0": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Loop2",
                            "value": 0
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_variable_Distinct_Email": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "Until_-_Loop2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Condition": {
                                "actions": {
                                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                        "inputs": {
                                            "name": "Details",
                                            "value": {
                                                "Earned": "@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Earned']}",
                                                "Email": "@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Email']}",
                                                "Local": "@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Local']}",
                                                "Name": "@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Name']}"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "runAfter": {},
                                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                                    }
                                },
                                "expression": {
                                    "and": [
                                        {
                                            "equals": [
                                                "@variables('Email')",
                                                "@body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][variables('Loop2')]['Email']"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "If"
                            },
                            "Increment_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Loop2",
                                    "value": 1
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Condition": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "IncrementVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": "@equals(variables('Loop2'), length(array(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'])))",
                        "limit": {
                            "count": 60,
                            "timeout": "PT1H"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_variable_Details_to_null": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Until"
                    }
                },
                "expression": "@equals(variables('Loop1'), length(array(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_-_Distinct_Emails')?['resultsets']?['Table1'])))",
                "limit": {
                    "count": 60,
                    "timeout": "PT1H"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_-_Details": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Until"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westus2/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, extremely helpful. Was stuck on loop placement, this really explains it well. Thank you. I had a question but managed to sort it!